# Why are conditional statements not working in this example?

Tags: php

I'm a bit perplexed with this code. `$this->product` is an Object with 12 vars. The var_dump indicates that `$key` is a string.

```
foreach ($this->product as $key => $val) {
    if (($key !== "id") || ($key !== "weight")) {
        var_dump($key);
    } else {
        print_r("Success" . $key);
    }
}
```

Despite "id" and "weight" being present as var names and represented as strings within `$key` they are not caught with this conditional. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You have a logical error. `$key` will *always* be not `id` **or** not `weight`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant to do:

```
foreach ($this->product as $key => $val) {
    if (($key !== "id") && ($key !== "weight")) {
        var_dump($key);
    } else {
        print_r("Success" . $key);
    }
}
```

`(($key !== "id") || ($key !== "weight"))` is always true, `$key` can't be "id" and "weight" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If `key` == "id", then it doesn't == "weight", so it will always pass your if check.

Answer (score 0):

Well it will never get to the else statement because the key will be either not equal to "id" or not equal to "weight" in any case.

Change your conditional statement to $key !== "id" && $key !== "weight"

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional is catching where `$key` is not `"id"` OR it is not `"weight"` - so it will catch everything as `$key` cannot be both.

You mean to use:

```
if (($key !== "id") && ($key !== "weight")) {
    var_dump($key);
} else {
    // $key is "id" or "weight"
    print_r("Success" . $key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `$key !== 'id'` you may want to do a string compare like this `strcmp($key, 'id') != 0`. The `strcmp` function returns `0` when the strings match. See the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php